# What is the status of RxAndroidBle and RxJava3?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, rx-android, rxandroidble, rx-java3

RxAndroidBle is a great piece of software and has reduced development time for Ble projects and has increased stability and readability significantly.

I just want to ask, what the status is of the rxjava3 branch of RxAndroidBle?
It says it is a test branch and stale at this moment.
So is it not recommended to take the rxjava3 branch for production applications?

I wonder if there are future plans to concentrate on rxjava3, since on the RxJava page it says:

*The 2.x version is in maintenance mode and will be supported only through bugfixes until February 28, 2021.*

Greetings from t4rj4n

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question. This should probably be an issue on the project's Github page.

Answer (score 0):

RxAndroidBle added support for RxJava3 in version 1.15.0 on 13. June 2022. All releases after that have had support for both RxJava2 and RxJava3.

You can [find the releases on the Releases page on GitHub](https://github.com/dariuszseweryn/RxAndroidBle/releases).